# When is a Time Zone involved in date/time calculation?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I'm using the [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/index.html) API to deal with date-time in my web application. I have a bit of confusion about using/specifying a specific zone in date-time comparison.

I have two textboxes - one for discount start date and the other for discount end date. A user is able to choose a date from a jQuery date-time picker.

These two dates need to be compared based on some criteria like,

- The discount start date must be before the end date.
- Both dates must **not** be same and there must be a defined interval between these two dates.
- The discount end date must **not** be before the current date, the start date however can.

and some others.

The question is not about how to make these comparisons. It is about a zone. In this scenario, is it necessary to specify a zone.

More specifically, is it necessary to use [`DateTimeZone`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html)/[`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) or [`LocalDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) is sufficient to make such comparison, regarding the Joda API?

Comment: Well do you *want* a time zone to be involved? If so, which time zone? Should the discount expire everywhere in the world simultaneously (presumably at midnight in *some* time zone - which?) or should it expire at the end of the day "wherever you are"? (As an aside, when working with *date* intervals (without a time zone) I usually consider it most appropriate to make the end date inclusive, which would mean it should be valid for the start and end date to be the same, making it only valid on that single day.

Comment: "*Should the discount expire everywhere in the world simultaneously*"? Yes, that should. The time zone involved is `Asia/Kolkata`, regrading the Joda API.

Comment: Okay, so I think you've just provided your own answer: yes, you need to specify a time zone, which should be `Asia/Kolkata`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my personal exprience, when you are playing with date and time stuff; you must have to use timezone along with this. This will keep you accurate in date and time calculation especially in date and time with different zone. You can convert one date time with a time zone to another equivalent date time with different time zone. In Joda Time API, lot of method is there where you have to pass the timezone string or object of TimeZone for getting the correct date time.